# How to solve the problem that dragged column in datagridview too slow or miss when AllowUserToOrderColumns = true

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a winform application and there is a datagridview with the AllowUserToOrderColumns property set true. When user tried to drag column, sometimes it can't drag successfully. Need to try several times to drag column. Or sometimes I dragged the column but I dropped it, it didn't move.
I'm not sure it's because too much data or not. There are 50 columns and over hundred rows.
How can I solve this problem. Please help me. Thank you all for first.

Comment: Are there any custom cell/row handlers or paging enabled? I mean do you control the painting or content of these somehow or just set the datasource with static data of a simple datagridview?

Comment: There is no paging enabled. But when I receive the message (content of a telegram), It'll update data in datagridview. And I also set different colors for different cells to distinguish data